# Ne10 not able to execute sample using gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, arm, dynamic-linking

I need to use NEON instructions in an existing c++ code for achieving better performance on ARM platform(ARMv7 laptop running Ubuntu). After some research I found a library Ne10 which may help that purpose. Now I am stuck at this simple task of running a basic program using Ne10. I am trying to run a sample C program as given at

http://community.arm.com/groups/android-community/blog/2013/09/26/ne10-library-getting-started

I did the cmake and make successfully. The compiled files are saved inside the build folder. But I am not able to compile them using gcc. I gave the gcc options as suggested in the link.

```
$gcc –O2 -o sample sample.c  -I$NE10_INC_PATH -l:$NE10_LIB_PATH/libNE10.a
```

where $NE10_INC_PATH and $NE10_LIB_PATH are directories of source code and build respectively

It is giving error as

```
/tmp/ccfaq3Py.o: In function `main':
Ne10_Test2.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `ne10_addc_float_c'
Ne10_Test2.c:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `ne10_addc_float_neon'
```

Could the error be in giving the folder path for include directory and lib directory incorrect? What should be the correct format for the folder and lib directories? Please give an example.

I know it may be a pretty basic question for C programmers but I am a beginner in C who find it pretty difficult to understand even the setting of environment variables and execution of programs. To be frank I am feeling very dumb when asking this question. So please give your suggestions. Any helpful links to simple tutorials on including C or C++ libraries in C++ will also be extremely helpful

Comment: Those errors indicate that you are not linking against the ne10 library. I assume with "run them using gcc" you mean compile the test program? What does your GCC command line look like?

Comment: @PurpleAlien added the gcc command in the question. I just used the suggestion from the link

Comment: Can you make sure that $NE10_LIB_PATH/libNE10.a actually exists? Those should point to where your headers and compiled library is located. Normally I would have expected to see a path there, unless you set those variables?

Comment: Try `echo $NE10_LIB_PATH` and `echo $NE10_INC_PATH` to see if you set those variables. If nothing shows up in the terminal set them like this:
`export NE10_LIB_PATH=/path/to/path/folder` and `export NE10_INC_PATH=/path/to/inc/folder`

Comment: @t.pimentel, or use env NE10_LIB_PATH=/path/to/path/folder NE10_INC_PATH=/path/to/inc/folder gcc ...